# Is there a way to send a form data that has integers and strings?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, html, forms

Often when sending a forms using ajax and jQuery, the method `$(this).serialize()` or `$(this).serializeArray()` is used to transform the form into a JSON object. The problem is that all the values in the JSON are of type string.I have a form with inputs that have numbers:

```
<label for="name">name:</label>
<input class="w-input input" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" type="text" required>

<label for="age">Age</label>
<input class=input" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Enter your age" type="number" required>
```

is there a way to still transform the form into a JSON but keep the types as it is required in the form, meaning still having my input that suppose to be numbers be numbers in the JSON.

Comment: not really ... what specific problem is it causing?

Comment: maybe add a data-attribute with input type so you can parse it on your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this behavior please use the following custom code:

JS

```
function serialize(form_id) {
    var inputs = document.getElementById(form_id).getElementsByTagName("input");
    var result = []
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var value = inputs[i].type == "number" ? inputs[i].value * 1 : inputs[i].type;

        var obj = {
            "value": value
        };
        if (inputs[i].name)
            obj["name"] = inputs[i].name;
        result.push(obj);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and the same HTML code:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform">
    <label for="name">name:</label>
    <input class="w-input input" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" value="Amr" type="text" required>

    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input class="input" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Enter your age" value="19" type="number" required>
</form>
```

and test using:

```
serialize("myform");
```

Comment: You are very welcome, what is the change so any one have the same question can know the final answer ?